# Check if a value contains a String character

Tags: javascript

Now i have a textfield and in javascript i wish to check if the value of this textfield is or contains a String.

I have tried the following:

```
      if(isNaN(parseInt($(this).val()))){}
```

Without effect.

ive also tried:

```
        if(typeof(parseInt($(this).val())) === "string"){}
```

ALTHOUGH these two examples might seem to work. They don't if you simply put the first character as a number then the rest of it wont matter.

So my question is how ?

Comment: The value of an element is always a string, so this one is pretty much given ?

Comment: I know  but i want to change that variable to an int and check if it is an int

Comment: Well, that's not what you're asking for, to check if something is an integer you do `!isNaN(value)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a regex to check if the value contains anything but a number :

```
/\D/.test(this.value)
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/yqJhH/)

Answer (score 1):

You can split the string into a character array and check each individually:

```
var s = "11test";
var split_s = s.split("");

for(var index=0;index<split_s.length;index++) {
    if(isNaN(parseInt(split_s[index]))){

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  if(!isNaN(parseInt($(this).val())) && $(this).val().length==parseInt($(this).val()).length) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(typeof($(this).val()) == "string"){//is a string
    //do something with string
}else if(typeof($(this).val()) == "object"){//is a object
    if($(this).val().length != undefined){//is a array
       //do something with array
    }else{//is a object
      //do something with json object
    }
}
```